# Retrieve iframe div elements text content

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'll look for a way to retrieve the text from a div (called: `#embeddedDateField`) in an iframe to an other page.

I've got the `var theIframe = window.frames['my-frame'].document`

But after that I have no idea how to get the element out of there and in to an other `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `contents()` method to get to iframe contents and find the required element in it.

```
$('iframeSelector').contents().find('#embeddedDateField')
```

Reference: [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: Yeah, I copied and pasted from the edit screen to complete my code. Basically, I made a mess :). You'll notice I'm back to using my code :). Again, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows you to specify the scope of your search:

```
$('#embeddedDateField', window.frames['my-frame'].document).doStuff()
```

I suggest attaching to the onload event of the frame to make sure the DOM is ready:

```
$("#my-frame").ready(function () {
    $('#embeddedDateField', window.frames['my-frame'].document).doStuff()
});
```